# Regex for finding url

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all

```
<a href="http://newday.com/song.mp3">First Link</a>
<div id="right_song"> 
        <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Pitbull ft. Chris Brown - Pitbull feat. Chris Brown - International Love mp3</b></div> 
        <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
<div style="float:left;"> 
    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;"> 
        <div style="float:left;"> 
    <a href="http://secondurl.com/thisoneshouldonlyoutput" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Second Link</a></div>';
```

I want to get out the second link from this html using pregmatch_all. My current regex looks like this:

```
preg_match_all("/\<a.+?href=(\"|')(?!javascript:|#)(.+?)\.mp3(\"|')/i", $html, $urlMatches);
```

This works fine and I get two links output, but I only want the second one to be output which is without .mp3 extension. Please help me

Comment: we don't parse html with regex

Comment: Parse HTML DOM with an HTML DOM parser - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I know that I shouldn't use regex but I have to for the moment. Any help?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will

- match the first anchor tag after `<div id="rigth_song">` which has an href attribute whose value ends with `.mp3`
- will avoid many of the edge cases which make matching html text with a regular expression very difficult.

`<div\sid="right_song">.*?<a(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=(['"]?)(.*?\.mp3)\1(?:\s|\/>|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>.*?<\/a>`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the difficult edge case in the second anchor tag, like string `href="bad.mp3"` is nested inside an attribute value; there is a javascript greater then sign `>` inside a value; and the real href attribute is without quotes.

```
<a href="http://newday.com/song.mp3">First Link</a>
<div id="right_song"> 
        <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Pitbull ft. Chris Brown - Pitbull feat. Chris Brown - International Love mp3</b></div> 
        <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
<div style="float:left;"> 
    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;"> 
        <div style="float:left;"> 
<a onmouseover=' href="bad.mp3" ; if ( 6 > x ) {funRotate(href); } ; ' href="http://secondurl.com/thisoneshouldonlyoutput.mp3">First Link</a>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match('/<div\sid="right_song">.*?<a(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=([\'"]?)(.*?\.mp3)\1(?:\s|\/>|>))(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*>.*?<\/a>
/imsx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Match**

Group 0 gets the text from the `<div` through to an including the full matching anchor tag
Group 1 gets the opening quote around the href value which is back referenced later
Group 2 gets the href value

```
[0] => <div id="right_song"> 
        <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Pitbull ft. Chris Brown - Pitbull feat. Chris Brown - International Love mp3</b></div> 
        <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
<div style="float:left;"> 
    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;"> 
        <div style="float:left;"> 
<a onmouseover=' href="bad.mp3" ; if ( 6 > x ) {funRotate(href); } ; ' href="http://secondurl.com/thisoneshouldonlyoutput.mp3">First Link</a>
[1] => "
[2] => http://secondurl.com/thisoneshouldonlyoutput.mp3
```

Comment: Isn't it possible just add div id verification or div style verification?

Comment: Your sample text does not have balanced open and close div tag. This is about the limit of what a regular expression can do with matching strings inside an html document. Matching nested div tags is an order of magnitude more complex of a problem. If you know it's the second match on the page, then you'd be best off just taking the second match, other wise you're stuck creating a buggy regex, or using a parsing tool.

Comment: The html code is being loaded from internet and I have no control over how it is coded. Thanks anyway

Comment: I updated the expression to match the first anchor tag after the desired div tag. this does allow many extra edge cases which may not be handled as expected.